# modificar jlabel segun usuario logeado java

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing

Necesito modificar un Jlabel de la pagina principal segun el usuario que se haya logeado en el Frame de Login.

Dejo el codigo que estoy trabajando, por si me pueden ayudar. Quedo atento a sus respuestas

```
  void generarNombre() {

    String sql = "Select CONCAT(nombre_usuario, ' ', apellido_usuario) As Nombre From usuarios;";
    conectar cc = new conectar();
    //    Connection cn = (Connection) cc.conexion();
    try {
        java.sql.Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            //Aca le digo que muestre el valor en un JtextFiel

            lb_usuario_recepcionista.setText(rs.getString("Nombre"));

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // NOTA: So hubo error muestra el error
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: no entiendo cual es el problema, porque no simplemente le cambias el texto al jlabel como lo haces con el jTextField?

Comment: La idea es que aparezca el nombre de la persona que se logeo en el "sistema" ... el problema es que no me carga el jlabel, es decir no cambia

Comment: intenta con lb.repaint() debajo del setText(); o repaint(); debajo del mismo

Comment: No entiendo. Si al JLabel le haces un setText(rs.getString("Nombre")) no te cambia?. No sera que realmente no estas haciendo el setText al JLabel que tienes en pantalla. Igual has puesto uno encima de otro, a veces pasa.

Comment: Efectivamente me funciono el lb.repaint();

Comment: Quedo de esta manera

                lb_usuario_recepcionista.setText(rs.getString("Nombre"));
                lb_usuario_recepcionista.repaint();

Answer (score 2):

Si obtienes el valor puedes posteriormente refrescar/repintar un valor en tu [JLabel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) mediante el método `repaint()`.

```
   ... 
   while (rs.next()) {
        //Aca le digo que muestre el valor en un JtextFiel
        lb_usuario_recepcionista.setText(rs.getString("Nombre"));
    }
   lb_usuario_recepcionista.repaint();
   ...
```